# Convertir el codigo en una funcion reutilziable

Tags: javascript, array, function

Tengo una variable que realmente la quiero convertir en una funcion para donde pone "Forestal"

pueda introducir el dato de una variable, como puedo transformar esto a funcion?

```
const categoriesbbdd = categories.categoriesData
let color = categoriesbbdd.filter((x)=> x.name === "Forestal")
color = color[0].color console.log(color);
```

categoriesbbdd es:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "color": "#05ab5b",
    "name": "Forestal",
    "description": "Forestal"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "color": "#0583ab",
    "name": "Acuíferos",
    "description": "Acuíferos"
  }
]
```

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas, Alba. Tu función recibe un sólo objeto, un string o una colección de objetos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que dado un nombre, quieres obtener el color correspondiente. Esto lo puedes hacer así:

```
function getColor(categoriesbbdd, name) {
  return categoriesbbdd.find(element=> element.name === name)?.color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esta respuesta vamos a asumir algunos escenarios.

##### Un parámetro -> varios elementos retornados

Si deseas crear una función que reciba un parámetro y devuelva los elementos que cumplen con la condición, entonces puedes utilizar [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) que te devuelve un **arreglo** con los elementos que cumplan dicha condición:

```
const funcionFiltrado  = (filtro) => datos.filter(x=> x.name === filtro);

console.log(funcionFiltrado("Forestal"));
 // respuesta: (un arreglo de objetos)
 /*[{
      color: "#05ab5b",
      description: "Forestal",
      id: 1,
      name: "Forestal"
 }]*/
```

##### Un parámetro -> un elemento retornado

Si deseas obtener el primer elemento, como en la respuesta de Pablo, puedes utilizar [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) que devuelve el primer elemento que cumpla con la condición, aunque existan otros.

```
const funcionFiltrado  = (filtro) => datos.find(x=> x.name === filtro);

 console.log(funcionFiltrado("Forestal"));
 // respuesta: (un objeto)
 /* {
      color: "#05ab5b",
      description: "Forestal",
      id: 1,
      name: "Forestal"
 } */
```

##### Filtrar por un arreglo de elementos -> varios elementos retornados

Si deseas filtrar la lista con un arreglo de filtros, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
const filtrarPorVarios = (filtros)=> datos.filter(x=> 
filtros.includes(x.name));
console.log("Filtrar por varias propiedades")
console.log(filtrarPorVarios(["Forestal", "Acuíferos"]));

// respuesta
    /*[{
          color: "#05ab5b",
          description: "Forestal",
          id: 1,
          name: "Forestal"
        }, 
        {
          color: "#0583ab",
          description: "Acuíferos",
          id: 2,
          name: "Acuíferos"
      }]*/
```

Puedes ver los ejemplos en acción en este JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8t0ym41d/